# Using Docker, how to change bash version inside Dockefile?

Tags: bash, docker, dockerfile, docker-build

When I login into a running container, and issue a bash --version command I am seeing the following

```
root@sb-core-repo-7988897977-rdtkb:/myapp# bash --version
GNU bash, version 5.0.3(1)-release (x86_64-pc-linux-gnu)
Copyright (C) 2019 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
 
This is free software; you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
```

Since, this GNU bash version 5.0.3 has a vulnerability, I would like to update the bash to 5.1.2 apparently, the vulnerability has been fixed in that release. as per [vulnerability](https://security-tracker.debian.org/tracker/CVE-2019-18276)

How and what can I update in the Dockerfile to update the bash version?

My Dockerfile is like this:

```
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/aspnet:3.1 AS base
WORKDIR /myapp
EXPOSE 80
 
## Installing tools for dotnet core
FROM mcr.microsoft.com/dotnet/core/sdk:3.1 As pre-build
RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y openjdk-11-jre
ENV PATH="$PATH:/root/.dotnet/tools"
 
FROM pre-build AS build
WORKDIR /src
COPY ["PhantomService.Application/PhantomService.Application.csproj", "PhantomService.Application/"]
COPY ["PhantomService.RestApi/NuGet.Config", "PhantomService.RestApi/"]
 
RUN dotnet restore "PhantomService.RestApi/PhantomService.RestApi.csproj" --configfile "PhantomService.RestApi/NuGet.Config"
 
## Build and Test
RUN dotnet build "PhantomService.RestApi/PhantomService.RestApi.csproj" -c Release -o /myapp
 
FROM build AS publish
RUN dotnet publish "PhantomService.RestApi/PhantomService.RestApi.csproj" -c Release -o /myapp
 
FROM base AS final
WORKDIR /myapp
COPY --from=publish /myapp .
ENTRYPOINT ["dotnet", "PhantomService.RestApi.dll"]
```

appreciate all the help and advice

Comment: The short answer is "you don't". Your base image is built on top of Debian 10, and it looks like the image is already running the latest `bash` package for that distribution. Furthermore, looking at the vulnerability, I don't think it's going to be relevant for what you're doing (do you expect unknown people to be running bash inside your container?). Lastly, it's possible the vulnerability has already been patched in the `bash` package; you would probably need to check the appropriate package sources.

Comment: Is it possible to block unknown people to bash into my container. So appreciate if you can point me in the right direction. Not sure how to check if the distribution has the latest bash already I looked around but I couldn't find it

Comment: How to resolve this vulnerability

Comment: I don't think this vunln is particularly relevant in the context of a Docker container. You could (and should not, but could) rm /bin/bash, which would MAKE IT MORE DIFFICULT (but NOT impossible) to run bash.

Comment: Anyone who can `docker run` your container or `docker exec` a shell in it can also trivially use Docker to root the host.  If your container's main process isn't itself `bash` (and it probably isn't) I wouldn't especially worry about this.  (That CVE page suggests Debian Buster doesn't have a fix, and that's a pretty common Debian version for Docker images.)